# Symfony 3.3.6 request parameters

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I can see the parameters are populated when I **dump($request->request)**

```
ParameterBag {#69 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "form" => array:8 [▼
      "phone" => "2042333233"
      "price" => "72"
      "region" => "1"
      "accept_terms" => "1"
      "_token" => "XXX"
    ]
  ]
}
```

But when I try to access the parameters:

```
$request->get('phone')
$request->request->get('phone')
```

The request is populated from a POST - so the latter should work but results in NULL???

Comment: Are you using a Symfony form or hard-coded form?

Comment: A hard-coded (dynamic) form - I thought that was implied via the call to createFormBuilder() instead of createForm()?? Is there a different way?

Comment: Show us what your form looks like - if you're using a form/form builder there's a better way to retrieve data than directly through the `Request` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy this:

```
$request->request->get('form')['phone']
```

Comment: Thats what did it - but I am not sure I understand why? None of the official docs I read seem to demonstrate this - what am I missing?

Comment: Because your `phone` value is into of `array` form

Comment: It is how the form component generates element names.  The form component supports nested forms so it needs an array to map everything properly.  From a browser, take a look at the generated html code using ctrl-u.  Might make things a bit clearer.